# How do I delete a file in S3 with C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete a file in S3 using C# code:

```
string _bucketName = "mybucket-ap-southeast-1-123627123717";
string _filename "ronaldo.png";

AmazonS3Config _config = new AmazonS3Config();
_config.ServiceURL = HOSTNAME + _bucketName;

IAmazonS3 _client = new AmazonS3Client(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET, _config);
await _client.DeleteObjectAsync(
    new Amazon.S3.Model.DeleteObjectRequest { BucketName = _bucketName, Key = _fileName });
```

The code does not throw any exception or error, but when I check and refresh the AWS S3 Management console the file is still there! What have I missed?

Comment: What is the return value you get from the `DeleteObjectAsync()` call? It might give information about your request.

Comment: DeleteObjectResponse _deleteObjectResponse = await _client.DeleteObjectAsync(new Amazon.S3.Model.DeleteObjectRequest { BucketName = _bucketName, Key = _fileName });


      DeleteMarker returns null

Comment: What `DeleteMarker`? And what are the values inside you get from inside the `_deleteObjectResponse` object? Do they contain a message and/or status of the request you sent? Please [edit] your question to include all the new information you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
  IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_appConfiguration["AWS:AccessKey"], _appConfiguration["AWS:SecretKey"], RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

  var deleteObjectRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest { BucketName = "BucketName ", Key = "key"};
  s3Client.DeleteObjectAsync(deleteObjectRequest).Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IAmazonS3 _client1 = new AmazonS3Client(AwsAccessKeyId, AwsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.APSouth1);
              
var deleteRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest
{

    Key = YourFolderName/YourFileName,
    BucketName = YourBucketName,

};
await _client1.DeleteObjectAsync(deleteRequest);
```

Use this its working fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).